# I cant end getline when see ' - ' character, can someone help me getline() ifstream in c++

Tags: c++, ifstream

```
ifstream InPut;
ofstream OutPut;
InPut.open("/Users/apple/Documents/Lập trình C++/OOP/Tập tin/Test1/Test1/FileIn.txt",ios_base::in);

string str, mssv;

getline(InPut,str);
InPut.seekg(1,ios_base::cur);
getline(InPut,mssv);
InPut.close();
cout<<""<<str<<"/"<<mssv;
return 0;
```

FileIn.txt:

> Nguyen Xuan Sang-1520159

I just want to read "Nguyen Xuan Sang", but my code reads in all of FileIn.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computers can't read your mind. You never told it to read to the "-", so the computer has no way of knowing at all if you want to read until a space, line break, or something else.

`getline()` defaults to using a nextline as the delimiter, which in your case seems to cause it to read the whole file.

To tell `getline()` to read until a "-", specify the character as the third argument like this:

```
getline(InPut, str, '-');
```

Comment: thanks for help, but in visual i can use getline(InPut, str, '-'); and str just read Nguyen Xuan Sang, but now i use xcode, i cant do like this.